# dropdownlist values from jquery are not recognized in c# code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get a selected item from asp.net dropdownlist control which is populated from jquery ajax call. I am able to loop through the items on the screen, see the options attached in the source of the page but when I am trying to get the value from the c# backend code I am getting blank value. 
This is what I have:

```
   $('#<%=Button2.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                var Dropdown2 = $('#<%=ddlListAgents.ClientID %>');
                  Dropdown2.empty();
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "WebForm3.aspx/fetchData",
                      data: "{selectedAgent: '" + $('#<%=txtAgentNameText.ClientID %>').val() +"'}",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function (response) {
                          Dropdown2.append(new Option("--Select Agent --", 0));
                          $.each(response.d, function (index, item) {
                              Dropdown2.append(new Option(item.Name, item.ID));
                          });
                      },
                      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                          alert(xhr.status);
                          alert(thrownError);
                      }
                  });
            });
```

Everything is set ok after that call and I am able to browse the options. But when I am clicking a button and trying to get the selected value in this code (test code):

```
protected void btnSelectAgentAdd_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in ddlListAgents.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected.Equals(true))
                {
                    item.Value.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            string one = ddlListAgents.SelectedValue;
        }
```

After the first loop the code steps out from the for loop, and the ddlListAgents.SelectedValue is equal to empty string.

This is the method I am using to get the dataset:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<AgentName> fetchData(string selectedAgent)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    BL.Client client = new BL.Client();                              
    var agents = new List<AgentName>();
    if (selectedAgent != string.Empty)
    {
        list = client.GetAgentNamesForPopupSearch(selectedAgent);                   
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> val in list)
    {
        agents.Add(new AgentName { ID = Convert.ToInt32(val.Key), Name = val.Value });
    }
    return agents;
}
```

Every advice is welcome. 
Thanks in advance, Laziale

EDIT: 
Page Load event added:

```
  if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                BL.Client client = new BL.Client();
                list = client.GetAgentNamesForPolicies2(Convert.ToInt32(4));
                ddlAgentName.DataSource = list;
                ddlAgentName.DataTextField = "Value";
                ddlAgentName.DataValueField = "Key";
                ddlAgentName.DataBind();
                ddlAgentName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select Agent --", string.Empty));            
            }
```

Comment: can you update the question with page load event code?

Comment: You are populating the dropdownlist with javascript which is unknown to the server. Server knows whatever was databound to the dropdown on the last request. So it wont work. Suggestion: you can have a hidden field containing the selected value of the dropdown. Add a javscript to populate that field on the `onchange` of the dropdown; and instead of reading SelectedValue of dropdown, read the hidden field

Answer (score -1):

```
string selectedValue = Request.Form[ddlLanguage.UniqueID];
```